# Does Sci-Hub use malware and phishing to obtain researchers' login credentials?

Tags: security, internet, scientific-papers

There is a new BBC article, [*Police warn students to avoid science website*](https://www.bbc.com/news/education-56462390) about [Sci-Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub), a pirate site to circumvent paywalls on science journals.

> But Max Bruce, the City of London police's cyber protection officer, has urged universities to block the website on their networks because of the "threat posed by Sci-Hub to both the university and its students".

> "If you're tricked into revealing your log-in credentials, whether it's through the use of fake emails or malware, we know that Sci-Hub will then use those details to compromise your university's computer network in order to steal research papers," he said.

My understanding of how Sci-Hub operates was that researchers willingly and knowingly give their credentials as they are opposed to the publishers making a lot of money on access to papers. I don't have that verified.

Does Sci-Hub rely on stolen credentials from unwitting researchers?

Comment: The City of London Police have said this at https://www.cityoflondon.police.uk/news/city-of-london/news/2021/march/police-warn-students-and-universities-of-accessing-an-illegal-website-to-download-published-scientific-papers/ - my reading of  the [Police Intellectual Property Crime Unit](https://www.cityoflondon.police.uk/police-forces/city-of-london-police/areas/city-of-london/about-us/about-us/pipcu/) would not approve of Sci-Hub whatever its methods of gathering copies of research papers

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub#Article_sourcing and references therein ...

Comment: I do not understand the acceept-checkmark, given the current form of the Q? Claim-article is full of claims, with a curious focus. It is: last quote is what I found in my TL: 'a mere user visit to the site itself is diving into phishing territory'. The accepted A deals mainly with speculations about sth like 'backend/methods to get content for that site'  & not really much about plain visits. So, what is the focused claim to analyse here? Current Q & A seem to me to talk mainly past each other?

Comment: @LangLаngС I think it could be read as two claims, both of which are answered by the accepted answer: 1) Does Sci-Hub itself engage in phishing? No, according to its owner, and with no direct evidence to the contrary. 2) Does Sci-Hub _benefit from_, and indirectly encourage, phishing? Yes, there is evidence of phishing attacks, and an admission of "buying credentials" (which, if you think about it, is a bit like saying "I didn't steal any diamonds, but I bought them cheap from this trader in an unmarked van, who wouldn't say where he got them from").

Comment: @IMSoP You list 2 aspects of the 'backend'-angle. The headline I read and encapsulated in the last quote, I read as 'ordinary user goes to shub-site, uses only that, is exposed to phishing attempts and risks theft of his credentials by using/visiting that site, alone'. You seem to read: 'does shub, 'the team', use some kind of phishing, *elsewhere,* to get at stuff'? I think it might need to read, also, 'is the ordinary user-visible delivery site used for phishing (in which way ever)'? With yours, I then count 3 connected claims to dissect?

Comment: You might be interested: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/245185/how-plausible-is-this-article-on-how-scihub-acquires-its-papers

Comment: @LangLаngС, I agree to an extent. Maybe it could be made more clear in that answer. Now that I am thinking about it, the crux of my question was not whether my credentials will get stolen by visiting the site as I see that to be clearly false. I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121288/discussion-on-question-by-user2316602-does-sci-hub-use-malware-and-phishing-to-o).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The claim in the article that people who go to the Sci-Hub website are "very vulnerable to having their credentials stolen" is completely baseless, since Sci-Hub never asks for credentials or other personal information. I will instead address the question posed here, about the origin of the credentials obtained by Sci-Hub.

The Sci-Hub website does not provide a means for people at academic institutions to supply their own logins. They are obtained elsewhere. But is hacking involved?

According to an article entitled "[Sci-Hub unmasked](https://crln.acrl.org/index.php/crlnews/article/view/9457/10701)" published in *College & Research Libraries News* in 2016:

> Sci-Hub takes advantage of an active international market in stolen
> user credentials, where innocent users give up their passwords to
> phishing attacks targeting the university community. In one such email
> attack, the hacker poses as a library service manager by using a
> combination of two real library staff members’ names familiar to
> faculty. The email draws users to a familiar URL address but, instead
> of taking them to their own library server, sends them to a secondary
> page (see Figure 1) with similar branding, though hosted in New
> Zealand. Input typed into the username and password fields on this
> page is captured and later used to illegally access licensed content.

So basically they're claiming that Sci-Hub is provided with passwords by a hacker network. One of the authors of this article was interviewed in 2016 for [*The Chronicle of Higher Education*](https://www.chronicle.com/article/librarians-find-themselves-caught-between-journal-pirates-and-publishers/) and repeated the circumstances of this exact case. A screenshot of the phishing page is provided.

[image: phishing page]

Another article, published in 2020 in the rather obscure *[Journal of Interlibrary Loan, Document Delivery & Electronic Reserve](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/1072303X.2020.1749750)*, provides a similar story, adding that techniques have ramped up in recent years.

> These emails can be very convincing and count on the victim being overwhelmed by the volume of received emails to work. This method was used by Iranian hackers in 2018 and 2019, and it was reported that this same method was used to target 380 libraries. It is important to recognize that these attacks are getting smarter and harder to identify.

This article also included a screenshot, but I will not post it here.

When asked about the use of phished passwords, [Alexandra Elbakyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Elbakyan), the creator of Sci-Hub, told the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/this-student-put-50-million-stolen-research-articles-online-and-theyre-free/2016/03/30/7714ffb4-eaf7-11e5-b0fd-073d5930a7b7_story.html) in a 2016 article, “It may be well possible that phished passwords ended up being used at Sci-Hub. I did not send any phishing emails to anyone myself. The exact source of the passwords was never personally important to me.”

In the same year she said [the same thing](https://svpow.com/2016/02/25/does-sci-hub-phish-for-credentials/) to a blogger: "So it may well be possible that this professor’s password finally ended up being used on Sci-Hub website. [...] At this moment I prefer not to disclose the thorough details of Sci-Hub operation, but I expect this to become possible in future."

In response to the new allegations in the UK, she [told Sky News](https://news.sky.com/story/police-warn-students-and-universities-against-using-the-pirate-bay-of-science-12250407) in 2021 that  "I bought some credentials from other people. Perhaps some credentials (out of thousands used by Sci-Hub) were phished but not by Sci-Hub itself."

It appears Elbakyan has acknowledged that that passwords obtained from hacking rings seem to be used by Sci-Hub, and there is at least one instance where it is claimed that these hackers phished an individual user. I do not see any *public* claims of malware other than this BBC article.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree that the original article jumped freely between "SciHub uses credentials stolen from phishing/malware attacks" and "SciHub users are being subjected to phishing/malware attacks" (and perhaps a third claim, between the two: "SciHub steals credentials to use on its site) and sowed confusion, but I think the question is about the former, not the latter. Perhaps a second question is required?

Comment: @Oddthinking The OP surely seems to think that the question is the former (according to their last comment) but sorry, I don’t see It: the *question text* is clearly asking about the risk of phishing *posed by Sci-Hub*. If that wasn’t OP’s intent then the question should be rewritten (and would become pretty boring, in my view: the much more interesting question is as currently posed, especially since the answer appears to be: the BBC and the police are knowingly spreading lies).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I've tweaked it a little to make it clearer (and arguably more boring), and encourage you to ask the second question if you are interested.

Comment: @Oddthinking The title of the Q is still not focused enough. The intent of the original article seemed to be to make visitors to the site to abstain from ever clicking on it, exemplified by the now removed 3rd quote, and still at least maybe to be read into the current title. Laser focus on claims is fine, but I''d pretty much prefer to either include a multi-facet Q *(and this A to also tackle that sub-point)* – or to make the Qtitle less ambigiuous as to simple visit/use included or not. Currently, to me title reads as 'mere visit included' (claim: "warning: users at risk").

Answer (score 12):

Does Sci-Hub rely on stolen credentials from unwitting researchers? Yes, at least in part. This is confirmed by Alexandra Elbakyan herself, although she also claims that Sci-Hub isn't the one conducting the phishing attacks:

> "I bought some credentials from other people," she told Sky News. "Perhaps some credentials (out of thousands used by Sci-Hub) were phished but not by Sci-Hub itself."

[Source](https://news.sky.com/story/police-warn-students-and-universities-against-using-the-pirate-bay-of-science-12250407)

She didn't clarify who the "other people" are, but if she's buying credentials, I assume it's from hackers (since nobody else would be selling).

**Edit**: Obviously, if Alexandra Elbakyan is buying credentials, the credentials could not have been donated, since people who donate their credentials do not request payment. [Sci-Hub does claim some of the credentials they use are donated](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/352/6285/508.full), which is not verifiable from the outside. I am also not aware of anyone who has publicly said they have donated their credentials to Sci-Hub - which is not surprising, since there are almost surely institutional policies against leaking one's credentials.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121164/discussion-on-answer-by-allure-does-sci-hub-use-malware-and-phishing-to-obtain-r).

Comment: This answer does lean a bit on the "theoretical" side. The quote concedes it's a possibility, and that's followed by the reasoning "if they're purchased, they're phished". I personally would change the "yes" conclusion to "likely" or similar, because it is the case here that there's no proof provided in the answer. That's preventing my upvote here.

Comment: Also, this concession (and the potential actual purchase of credentials) may be (partially) to provide an argument for plausible deniability to "donators". They are definitely not interested in providing an easy way to find out which (or even how many) of the credentials they use are freely given.